# How best to convert a time to double and back while preserving the time in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, time

In my swift application I'm using a time that I want to randomize between a certain interval. I have a start interval and an end interval. As a result, I am converting a certain time (e.g. 14:34) into a double, so that I can use `Double.random(in: startInterval ... endInterval)` to get a random time in the interval. Then I'm converting back into an int version of the time. How's the best way to do this? Currently I have this, but it's not working quite right:

```
public static func convertToTimeDouble(hour: Int, minute: Int) -> Double {

    return Double(hour) + (Double(minute) / 60.0)

}

public static func extractHourFromTimeDouble(alarmTimeDouble: Double) -> Int {

    return Int(floor(alarmTimeDouble))

}

public static func extractMinuteFromTimeDouble(alarmTimeDouble: Double) -> Int {

    return Int(floor((alarmTimeDouble - floor(alarmTimeDouble)) * 60)

}
```

Comment: What does “but it's not working quite right“ mean?

Answer (score 2):

You are going about this a very hard way.

`Date` objects can be very easily converted to floating point numbers using the method timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate. That gives you a number of seconds since an arbitrary "epoch date". You can then do math on those time intervals to calculate differences in seconds.

Doing math in hours, minutes, and seconds you are better off using a `Calendar` object and methods that deal with `DateComponents`. There are whole groups of methods that let you extract the year, monty, day, hours, minutes, seconds, etc from dates using the current calendar and time zone.

You should learn to use the system methods. They do all the heavy lifting for you, with code that is well tested and handles all the different odd edge cases like daylight savings time, leap years, etc.

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out. All I needed to do was change floor to round in the minute function and not the hour function. Final version is this:

```
public static func convertToTimeDouble(hour: Int, minute: Int) -> Double {

    return Double(hour) + (Double(minute) / 60.0)

}

public static func extractHourFromTimeDouble(alarmTimeDouble: Double) -> Int {

    return Int(floor(alarmTimeDouble))

}

public static func extractMinuteFromTimeDouble(alarmTimeDouble: Double) -> Int {

    return Int(round((alarmTimeDouble - floor(alarmTimeDouble)) * 60))

}
```